# Store image from UIImagePickerController in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, image, uiimagepickercontroller, direction

I have tried to store image (`NSUserDefault`) from `UIImagePickerController` in iPhone.

This way to stored image:

[image]

```
-(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *originalImage=[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    NSData * imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(originalImage);
    NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [user setValue:imageData forKey:@"pictureData"];
}
```

This way to retrieve image:

```
NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:[user valueForKey:@"pictureData"]];
[btn2 setImage:myImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image]

When i retrieve the image from `NSUserDefaults` to set `UIButton`, finally the image shown, but the direction changes from bottom to right, How to fix this issue? Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` to store an image into `NSUserDefaults` this way:

```
NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(originalImage, 90);
NSUserDefaults *user = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[user setValue:imageData forKey:@"pictureData"];
```

Answer (score 2):

A `UIImage` has a property `imageOrientation`, which instructs the `UIImageView` and other `UIImage` consumers to rotate the raw image data. There's a good chance that this flag is being saved to the exif data in the uploaded jpeg image, but the program you use to view it is not honoring that flag.

To rotate the `UIImage` to display properly when uploaded, you can use a category like this:

**UIImage+fixOrientation.h**

```
@interface UIImage (fixOrientation)

 - (UIImage *)fixOrientation;

@end
```

**UIImage+fixOrientation.m**

```
@implementation UIImage (fixOrientation)

 - (UIImage *)fixOrientation {

// No-op if the orientation is already correct
if (self.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp) return self;

// We need to calculate the proper transformation to make the image upright.
// We do it in 2 steps: Rotate if Left/Right/Down, and then flip if Mirrored.
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

switch (self.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, self.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, M_PI_2);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationRight:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, 0, self.size.height);
        transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, -M_PI_2);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
        break;
}

switch (self.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationUpMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationDownMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.width, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;

    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, self.size.height, 0);
        transform = CGAffineTransformScale(transform, -1, 1);
        break;
    case UIImageOrientationUp:
    case UIImageOrientationDown:
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
        break;
}

// Now we draw the underlying CGImage into a new context, applying the transform
// calculated above.
CGContextRef ctx = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, self.size.width, self.size.height,
                                         CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(self.CGImage), 0,
                                         CGImageGetColorSpace(self.CGImage),
                                         CGImageGetBitmapInfo(self.CGImage));
CGContextConcatCTM(ctx, transform);
switch (self.imageOrientation) {
    case UIImageOrientationLeft:
    case UIImageOrientationLeftMirrored:
    case UIImageOrientationRight:
    case UIImageOrientationRightMirrored:
        // Grr...
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.height,self.size.width), self.CGImage);
        break;

    default:
        CGContextDrawImage(ctx, CGRectMake(0,0,self.size.width,self.size.height), self.CGImage);
        break;
}

// And now we just create a new UIImage from the drawing context
CGImageRef cgimg = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(ctx);
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgimg];
CGContextRelease(ctx);
CGImageRelease(cgimg);
return img;
}

@end
```